# Internal Server Error when using .access file

Tags: internal

I am trying to make A vanity urls but for some reason when i add the .htaccess to my local machine. Im getting

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

I'm using wamp, Yes I have ticked mod_rewrite and tries adding it manually still no luck?

what could it be doing this.

Heres the code

```
**********
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond﻿ %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ [http://localhostpath/file.php?u=$] [NC]
**********
```

Ive tried everything possible and by googling results.

Comment: Are you sure the asteriks for decoration are valid (I have a little experience with `.htaccess` files, but they seem out of place

Comment: Everything seems fine with the code, I have even tried multiply codes and done youtube tutorials on .htaccess. Nothing seems to work and I also have little experience  with .htacess myself

Comment: Also, your `RewriteCond`s look incomplete to me. Are you sure you're following the tutorail properly? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I will rewrite and post the you tube video directly here when I get home.

Comment: Ok Here is the video
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZw4XJuRw3U

You may be able to twick it abit and it may work from there not to sure.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, take out the asteriks (top line and bottom line). I just tried it on my server to make sure - they're not valid comments/decoration.

Secondly, I don't know why but when I copy your code directly, I get an error. If I retype it out exactly, it works. I really have no idea what this might be, although once I had a similar issue - where the code looked the same - but it turns out something was encoded differently/corrupted (although notepad++ was still able to figure it out, apache wasn't). So just try typing it out yourself.